# Performance difference depending on attribute order when using SSAS for data import in Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, mdx, sql-server-data-tools

Using a pivot table in Excel 2019, I imported data from the MDB SSAS server, placed 3 attributes on the row axis, and placed 3 measures on the row too.

A1 and A2 are in dimension A, and B1 is in dimension B.

When M1, M2, M3 (together M) are called the measure,
A table with 20,000 rows in dimension A and 100,000 rows in dimension B was used as the table source.

At this time, in the row

- B1>A2>A1>M
- A1>A2>B1>M
- B1>A1>A2>M

When do this in this order, executing so long even after a long time.
but

- A1>B1>A2>M

data comes out soon.

also If I set A1>B1>A2 and use M in the column, the data appear.

I changed the order and tested it in various ways.

I'm curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.